# How to split and concatenate the string to get the following result using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have a following string

```
var url="hrefpara1?##0##:##2##para2?##3##:##1##para3?##4##:##6##";
```

and i have array like this

```
var a=[Arun,Nandha,Gopi,praveen,jack];
```

I need a following string result:

```
hrefpara1?##Arun##:##Gopi##para2?##Praveen##:##Nandha##para3?##jack##:####;
```

How can i get this using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this

```
var url="hrefpara1?##0##:##2##para2?##3##:##1##para3?##4##:##6##";

var a=["Arun","Nandha","Gopi","praveen","jack"];


url = url.replace(/(##)([^#]*)(##)/g,function (match,prefix,index,suffix) {
    return (a[+index]) ?prefix+a[+index]+suffix : prefix+suffix;
});


console.log(url);
```

Comment: Works Fine. Can you able to Explain.

Comment: I'm using regular expression to find Your pattern `##digit##`, thanks to \g switch replace method will find the all occurance of this pattern. Pattern is split in three groups using parenthesis `(##)([^#]*)(##)` for better reference in callback function which make return changed string, callback function receive four parameters, first is the whole matched pattern, **prefix** hold value for the first group from patter `(##)` , **index** is for `([^#]*)` group and **suffix** is for last `(##)` group.

Comment: In function I just check if value for the index value exists in Your table, if not i return default patter, else i return value from table. I'm using `+index` for convert string into int

Comment: @Neophyte Do you have any questions?